# Windows XP Quick Launch shortcuts with WinKey

Tags: windows-xp, quicklaunch, windows-key

How can I make the <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>[number]</kbd> combination run the `[number]`th item in Windows XP's Quick Launch bar? In other words, I want to mimic the Windows 7 behavior.

Comment: Windows 7 does exactly that, although the whole taskbar is now a quick launch bar.

Comment: @Paranoid: :O OMG, how surprising! I had no idea Windows 7 did that, and it was a pure coincidence that I said `XP` in the title and the question!
(... lol, just kidding, I use it like fifty times per hour when I'm using Windows 7, and I want it in XP; that's why I asked. :P)

Answer (score 1):

Sure is, use HotKeyBind

http://www.technixupdate.com/assign-window-hotkeys-to-quick-launch-items-in-win-xp-with-hotkeybind/

> 1. First Download and install [HotKeyBind](http://hotkeybind.sourceforge.net/index.html).
> 2. You will see a gray colored icon in the task bar if it is running
> 3. Double click on this icon a new window will appear
> 4. Click on the Add button,  and select the option which says  Launch a File >> Executes a Program and Click Ok
> 5. Browse to the target quick launch items folder , path for it would be
>      :\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
>
> For Example:
>   C:\Documents and Settings\zapper\Application Data\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
>
> Note: Make sure the that Show hidden files and folder is set to shown in folder options before browsing to this path.
>   Other wise copy the path above and paste it in the address bar and drag the quick launch items on the target box.
>
> 6. After selecting the shortcut for the program like Gtalk in quick launch items click Ok
> 7. A New window will open up with title as Edit Keys , click the checkbox WIN and press any number key.
>
> As Google talk is the first item in my quick launch after Start button so I have set the shortcut for it as Win +1
>
> 8. That’s it Done

Comment: +1 because it works, but it doesn't actually do what I needed (I think I was vague about this, though). What this program does is *not* specific to Quick-Launch. By contrast, I was looking for a solution where `WinKey+N` would always execute the `N`th item in the Quick Launch bar, which this doesn't do.

Comment: The article says how to bind it to the quicklaunch?

Comment: No, it binds it to the *program*, which *happens* to be in the Quick Launch. If I move around the shortcuts in the quick launch bar, the keys will still be bound as they were before -- so WinKey+1 might launch program #4. It's not really binding to the icons but to the programs themselves, which isn't quite what I want.

Comment: I guess you could use process monitor to capture the event on a W7 pc, see how it is calling position 1 on the taskbar.

Comment: It's likely not something that you can see on Process Monitor -- it's probably just some window message, maybe better seen with Spy++. I could probably figure it out and write a program for it if I really want to, but if there's something already available I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a program to do this myself.

Base64-encoded version of my executable:

```
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
```

Source code:

```
//Flags:  /O1 /link /NoDefaultLib /entry:WinMainCRTStartup /Subsystem:Windows
//No need for a C runtime library...

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x502
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

static HHOOK hHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHook(IN int nCode,
                              IN WPARAM wParam, IN LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL suppress = FALSE;
    LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pKBDHS = (LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    int nKey = pKBDHS->vkCode - 0x30;
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN && 0 <= nKey && nKey <= 9)
    {
        if (nKey == 0)
        {
            /*Quit*/
            suppress = TRUE;
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        else if (GetKeyState(VK_LWIN) < 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RWIN) < 0)
        {
            HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
            if (hWnd != NULL)
            { hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, _T("Shell_TrayWnd"), NULL); }
            if (hWnd != NULL)
            { hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL, REBARCLASSNAME, NULL); }
            if (hWnd != NULL)
            {
                hWnd = FindWindowEx(hWnd, NULL,
                                    TOOLBARCLASSNAME, _T("Quick Launch"));
            }
            if (hWnd != NULL)
            {
                suppress = TRUE;
                DWORD btnSize = SendMessage(hWnd, TB_GETBUTTONSIZE, 0, 0);
                LONG coord = MAKELONG((nKey - 1) * LOWORD(btnSize), 0);
                PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, coord);
                PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, coord);
            }
        }
    }
    if (suppress) { return 1; }
    else if (hHook == NULL) { return 0; }
    else { return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam); }
}

int WinMainCRTStartup()
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &KeyboardHook, hInstance, 0);
    if (hHook != NULL && hHook != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MSG msg;
        BOOL success;
        while (success = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            if (success == -1) { break; }
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```